# Plotting a lineplot from a dataframe with many points takes a long time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have dataframe with X and Y coordinates and name of line
For example:

```
d = {'x': [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
     'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
     'name': ['name','name','name','name','name','name2','name2','name2','name2','name2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Dataframe has about 5000 different lines, each having around 300 points - so about 1.500.000 rows

I need to plot all the lines to one plot.

I tried seaborn:

```
fg = sns.lineplot(data=df, x="x", y="y", hue='name')
```

but it takes ages to run.

Is plotting directly from dataframe optimal or would splitting the dataframes to np arrays and then plotting be faster?

Comment: `df.info()` on your real dataframe to verify the x and y columns are numeric (int or float). seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib, and pandas.DataFrame.plot uses matplotlib and the default backend.

Comment: What are you hoping to see?  You can't possibly comprehend a graph with 5,000 different lines.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney both x a y columns are floats

I can did plot it using seaborn or matplotlib but it just take ages, main question is what is the optimal way to plot this type of dataframe.

Comment: @TimRoberts I can, for this usecase its quite important.

Comment: seaborn is the easiest way. it takes care of separating the data behind the scenes (with pandas). Since the [mre] isn't really representative of the issue, we can only **speculate**, which isn't how SO works

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Yeah sorry, the expmle can only go so far as the issue is the amount of data, my question focuses more to the general point to When I have dataframe structured like this what is the optimal way of plotting from it. Is the amount of data too big of an issue and it just takes its time or would there be another approach (such as creating 1 array per line name and plotting from that)

Comment: Wide form dataframes are usually with pandas, and longform dataframes are usually with seaborn

Comment: Regarding this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76417322/plotting-a-lineplot-from-a-dataframe-with-many-points-takes-a-long-time?noredirect=1#comment134748703_76417322). Just because it plots, doesn't mean they are numbers, which is why I requested you check `df.info()`. `str` types will plot just fine, but take forever. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2qIu.png). If it says `object`, you need to change the type with `.astype(float)`